# PHP with IIS Configuration

Tags: php, iis

I have got a PHP website that I am trying to set-up through IIS. I am following this video: 
http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-php-applications-on-iis/mix08-partying-with-php-on-microsoft-internet-information-services-7-and-above

When the person talks about adding your own features within  and specifies an Executable (php-cgi.exe), I get stuck since I don't have that.

However, the list of features within Handler Mappings already contains PHP53_via_FastCGI and PHP54_via_FastCGI.

The details of the website are:

**Site name:** MyWebsite

**Physical Path:** C:\MyWebsite

**IP Address:** All Unassigned

**Port:** 80

**Type:** http

**Host name:** www.MyWebsite.com (This url isn't mine. It's just something data I can put inside Host name for now)

Also, when I click on "Test Connection", it gives me the error: "Cannot verify access to path C:\MyWebsite

**Please please please please help.**

Comment: Did you allow access to that folder for your IIS user?

Comment: Can you please show me how I can do that?

Comment: Are you using active directory?

Comment: No. It's on my local machine. I'm using Windows 7

Comment: right click on the folder, and go to properties -> tab security -> add user and then do an search and select the iss user

Comment: To allow access to the folder to IIS user: Right click on c:\mywebsite -> properties -> security there you should see the permissions for different users.

Comment: I have put full control on all the users but it still has the same error.

Comment: Possibly better on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give access to the `IISUSR` user. On the security tab click `Edit` and then `Add` then type is IISUSR and click okay. Then make sure it has the needed permissions. IF this is a local host I would probably start with Full Control for now and go to read & execute after if you are goign to do anything more with it.